# Change the code of a booking widget in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a booking website with wordpress and i'm using a theme called Listeo.
The theme includes a booking widget that returns the products available all the dates between the day X and Y that the user chose. I would like to change the code of this widget so that it returns the products available in at least one day out of the dates X and Y.

I've identified the php file and code lines of the widget

```
function listeo_date_range_filter( $where ) {
    
    global $wpdb;

    $date_range = get_query_var( 'date_range' );
    
    if(!empty($date_range)) : 
//TODO replace / with - if first is day - month- year
        $dates = explode(' - ',$date_range);
        //setcookie('listeo_date_range', $date_range, time()+31556926);
        $date_start = $dates[0];
        $date_end = $dates[1];
        
        $date_start_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('!'.listeo_date_time_wp_format_php(), $date_start);
        $date_end_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('!'.listeo_date_time_wp_format_php(), $date_end);
        
        $format_date_start  = esc_sql($date_start_object->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $format_date_end    = esc_sql($date_end_object->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

        // $format_date_start = esc_sql ( date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $wpdb->esc_like( $date_start ) ) ) );
        // $format_date_end = esc_sql ( date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $wpdb->esc_like( $date_end ) ) ) );
        // //    
        // $booking_hours = Listeo_Core_Bookings_Calendar::wpk_change_booking_hours( $date_start, $date_end );
  //       $date_start = $booking_hours[ 'date_start' ];
  //       $date_end = $booking_hours[ 'date_end' ];

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'bookings_calendar';
            
        $where .= $GLOBALS['wpdb']->prepare(  " AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID ".
            'NOT IN ( '.
                'SELECT listing_id '.
                "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}bookings_calendar ".
                'WHERE 
                (( %s > date_start AND %s < date_end ) 
                OR 
                ( %s > date_start AND %s < date_end ) 
                OR 
                ( date_start >= %s AND date_end < %s ))
                AND type = "reservation" AND NOT status="cancelled" AND NOT status="expired"
                GROUP BY listing_id '.
            ' ) ', $format_date_start, $format_date_start, $format_date_end,  $format_date_end, $format_date_start, $format_date_end );
      
       //var_dump($where);
    endif;
    
    return $where;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. If you currently get _all_ the products between X and Y - then you must be getting "at least" the products for one day between X and Y already.

Comment: I'm getting the products that are available for all the days between X and Y, and i want the products that are available for at least one day between X and Y.